# C# Obtaining a generic IEnumerator from a generic array

Tags: c#, generics, multidimensional-array, mono, wrapper

I'm working in C# with the latest build of Unity3D and MonoDevelop (I believe C# version 6 is currently used in Unity but I may be wrong).

My current situation is, I have a wrapper class for a 2D array and I'd like to be able to iterate over it with a `foreach` like I would over a regular 2D array.

```
public class CoordArray<T> : IEnumerable<T> {

    // ... some other members
    private T[,] arr;

    public CoordArray(int width, int height) {
        // ... other intialization
        arr = new T[height, width];
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return arr.GetEnumerator();
    }

    ...
}

public class Foo {
    public void Bar() {
        CoordArray<Poop> array = new CoordArray<Poop>(23,213);
        foreach(Poop p in array) DoSomething(p);
    }
}
```

This `GetEnumerator()` method, however, throws the following error in Unity:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.IEnumerator` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I've found a few solutions to similar problems on this site and I've tried:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    return ((IEnumerable<T>) arr).GetEnumerator();
}
```

but this again gives me an error:

> Cannot convert type `T[,]` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`

I've also tried:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    return (IEnumerator<T>) arr.GetEnumerator();
}
```

,

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    return arr.Cast<T>().GetEnumerator();
}
```

and:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    foreach (T element in arr) yield return element;
}
```

but these all throw the following error:

> `CoordArray<T>` does not implement interface member `System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` and the best implementing candidate `CoordArray<T>.GetEnumerator()` return type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>` does not match interface member return type `System.Collections.IEnumerator`

and if I try:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    return arr.GetEnumerator();
}
```

the exact opposite error is thrown:

> `CoordArray<T>` does not implement interface member `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` and the best implementing candidate `CoordArray<T>.GetEnumerator()` return type `System.Collections.IEnumerator` does not match interface member return type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>`

and (quite obviously) it won't let me implement `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` simultaneously.

Is there a way to get a generic iterator from a generic array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that 2d array only "implements" the non generic `IEnumerable`. But you could use [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get `IEnumerable<T>` and then get the `IEnumerator<T>` from it:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return arr.Cast<T>().GetEnumerator();
}
```

Make sure you have included

```
using System.Linq;
```

If for some reason `Cast` method is not available, then I guess at least you can use C# iterator method (available since 2.0):

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (T element in arr)
        yield return element;
}
```

**Update:** The new compiler error you are getting is different. The above solves the implementation of the generic `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` method which I think is the target of your question. But since `IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable`, you also need to implement the non generic `GetEnumerator` method in your class as well (I was assuming you already did that). It needs to be implemented explicitly, so add the following to your class:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return arr.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: OP claims that "and I've tried a solution using arr.Cast<T>() but it said Cast was undefined."

Comment: @Evk Missed that part, thanks! Friday evening, probably time to rest :)

Comment: I've tried both of these (yes, the problem with `Cast` was that I wasn't importing `System.Linq`), but the same error is still being thrown. I've updated my OP now.

Comment: That's different - see the update. I was assuming you already have that - VS Implement Interface command automatically creates 2 method (implicit + explicit) skeleton and you only need to write the implementation.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Coming from Java's weak generics, it's a little unusual for me to have to implement a generic and non-generic version of the same method - at most you'd get a raw type or unsafe warning in similar situations. Out of curiosity, how come `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` can't be declared `public`?

Comment: It can, but one of the two has to be implemented *explicitly*. It's because in .NET you can't have 2 methods with one and the same name which differ only by the result type. But if you are asking why you can't use `public` modifier on explicit implementation, it's because the explicit implementation is considered `private`, so no access modifiers are allowed. Similar to interface members which are considered `public` and not access modifier is allowed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this suit your needs?

```cs
public class CoordArray<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{

    // ... some other members
    private T[,] arr;

    public CoordArray(int width, int height)
    {
        // ... other intialization
        arr = new T[height, width];
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> ArrAsEnumerableT
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var elmt in arr)
                yield return elmt;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ArrAsEnumerableT.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ArrAsEnumerableT.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work (it doesn't throw any errors at least). I haven't actually been able to test it yet though. It looks like some magic though, implementing 2 `GetEnumerator()` methods at the same time. How exactly does this work and why are both methods even required?